# Where to find multilingual and/or beautifully typeset Buddhist texts?

Tags: texts

I recently stumbled upon a lovely collection of well-typeset Vietnamese Buddhist texts. It must have taken tremendous effort to typeset [this](http://nigioikhatsi.net/kinhsach-pdf/nietban2015-01.pdf)  bilingual Chinese-Vietnamese edition of the Mahāparinirvāṇa Sūtra in LaTeX, for example.

As a computational linguist and Buddhism enthusiast, I would be highly interested to discover more sources of beautifully typeset multilingual Buddhist materials.

Answer (score 1):

- Beautifully typed texts - http://dharmafarer.org/, also http://www.thripitakaya.org/ and http://pitaka.lk/ but in Singhala
- Multilingual texts - https://suttacentral.net/ (you can say it is also beautifully formated), http://www.buddha-vacana.org/ (English and French)

Comment: Suttacentral makes a point to not format translations in multilingual manner